# Do the operations defined in array ops in Tensorflow have gradient defined?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, gradient

I want to know whether the tensorflow operations in [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc), have a gradient defined. I am asking because I am implementing a custom loss function and when I run it I always have this error :

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

This is my custom Loss function:

```
def calculate_additional_loss(y_true,y_pred):
#additional loss
x_decoded_normalized = original_dim* y_pred
#y_true = K.print_tensor(y_true, message='y_true = ')
#y_pred = K.print_tensor(y_pred, message='y_pred = ')
error = tf.constant(0, dtype= tf.float32)
additional_loss= tf.constant(0, dtype= tf.float32)
final_loss= tf.constant(0, dtype= tf.float32)
for k in range(batch_size):
    #add padding
    reshaped_elem_1 = K.reshape(x_decoded_normalized[k], [DIM,DIM])

    a = K.reshape(reshaped_elem_1[:,DIM-1], [DIM,1])
    b = K.reshape(reshaped_elem_1[:,1], [DIM,1])

    reshaped_elem_1 = tf.concat ([b,reshaped_elem_1], axis= 1)
    reshaped_elem_1 = tf.concat ([reshaped_elem_1,a], axis= 1)

    c= K.reshape(reshaped_elem_1[DIM-1,:], [1,DIM+2])
    d= K.reshape(reshaped_elem_1[1,:], [1,DIM+2])
    reshaped_elem_1 = tf.concat ([d,reshaped_elem_1],axis=0)
    reshaped_elem_1 = tf.concat ([reshaped_elem_1,c],axis=0)

    for (i,j) in range(reshaped_elem_1.shape[0],reshaped_elem_1.shape[1]):
        error = tf.add(error, tf.pow((reshaped_elem_1[i,j]- 
                       reshaped_elem_1[i,j+1]),-2), 
                       tf.pow((reshaped_elem_1[i,j]-reshaped_elem_1[i,j- 
                       1]),-2), tf.pow((reshaped_elem_1[i,j]- 
                       reshaped_elem_1[i-1,j]),-2), 
                       tf.pow((reshaped_elem_1[i,j]-reshaped_elem_1[i+1,j]),-2))
    additional_loss = tf.add(additional_loss, tf.divide(error, original_dim))
final_loss += tf.divide(additional_loss, batch_size)
print('final_loss', final_loss)
return final_loss
```

and This is where I am calling it:

```
models = (encoder, decoder)
additional_loss = calculate_additional_loss(inputs,outputs)
vae.add_loss(additional_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
vae.summary()

plot_model(vae,to_file='vae_mlp.png',show_shapes=True)
vae.fit(x_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, None), verbose = 1, callbacks=[CustomMetrics()])
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most  ops have a defined gradient. There are some ops for which a gradient is not defined and the error message you get gives you some examples.

Having said that, there are couple of mistakes I see in your code :

1. `final_loss` is defined as `tf.constant`, but you are trying to increment it.
2. You are taking a tuple from `range`
3. `error` is defined as `tf.constant`, but you are trying to increment it.
4. Don't use `for` loop in this way over `batch_size`. Instead use TensorFlow functions to handle `batch` dimension directly. This way you are just proliferating your nodes.
5. The way you have written your code makes me think that you're thinking of TensorFlow as pure python. It is not. You define the graph and then you execute it inside a session. So, in the function use TF functions to just define the computations.

Comment: Thank you @Ujjwal for your contribution. I have rectified point 1 and 3. Now _final_loss_ and _error_ are constants that are intialized to 0. Concerning point 4, I want to iterate inside the batch (my batch_size:10). I have found this TF function 'tf.train.batch' but I don't think it's helpful. Do you have any code suggestion for it please? I will edit my post to add where I am calling this additional_loss function.

Comment: In your code, all the operations you are doing inside the `loop`, can be done on a batch directly such as `reshape` and `concat`. So, you can eliminate the `for` loop entirely.

Constants are constants. If you initialize them to `0`, it is meant to stay like that forever. You will need to declare a `tf.Variable` if you wish to modify it.

Comment: concerning the for loop, I tried to compile the model without but I got this error :ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 360 elements to shape [6,6] (36 elements) for 'Reshape_100'. which is I think pretty logic. That's why I was iterating in the first place. My inputs has shape of (10,36) which means 10 vectors of 36 elements. I want to reshape each element. So what do you suggest in this case ?

Comment: You cannot just remove the for loop. You have to include the batch dimension in the ops .

Comment: Can you please give an example, a link that I can understand better what you mean

Comment: Can tf.scan be used in this case ?

Comment: From the documentation - `A tensor or (possibly nested) sequence of tensors, each of which will be unpacked along their first dimension. The nested sequence of the resulting slices will be the first argument to fn.` 
So, yes. You need to look at the documentation more clearly.

Comment: I think tf.scan cannot be used in our case because elems should be 1 dimensional array, I tried it with an array of dimension (2,4). I get this error : TypeError: fn() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179879/discussion-between-emna-jaoua-and-ujjwal).

Comment: I found a solution and it is working with Tensorflow graph but I couldn't integrate it withini keras, it is in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311186/add-custom-loss-function-to-keras